# Linux Server (Ubuntu Server 20.04) Loses Network Connectivity After One Day

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04. It loses internet connectivity periodically, seemingly every day, and requires me to manually intervene and run

```
dhclient -r
dhclient
```

to restore connectivity. Honestly, I don't really understand what these commands are doing. It was just luck that I just discovered that they "fix" it.

Before running the temporary fix, pinging a website from my server to a site out of my network fails, but pinging my server from another computer on the network succeeds.

Strangely, the VMs that run inside of the Ubuntu Server are still able to connect while this happens.

My only guess is that it is related to my dhcp lease but I'm not sure why this started happening or what to do about it.

I read the man pages at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/dhclient.conf.5.html but they kind of assume that you have a bit of knowledge going into it.

What is the best way to remedy this?

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I realized that I had the NETPLAN dhcp4 value set to false and was using NETPLAN to set the IP address, while having the router statically set the IP address, also. The values were in agreement but perhaps they were fighting over who handles the IP. I changed it so that the router handles it entirely. Even if that doesn't fix it, it seems like the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment above was the solution.

> I had the NETPLAN dhcp4 value set to false and was using NETPLAN to set the IP address, while having the router statically set the IP address, also. The values were in agreement but perhaps they were fighting over who handles the IP. I changed it so that the router handles it entirely.

So, `dhclient` is the Linux equivalent of `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /renew` (in Windows), so it was refreshing the connection every time I ran that.

My NETPLAN now looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno3:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

Comment: what exactly did you do? I am not familiar with these